# How to import OpenCV into python

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I have downloaded Anaconda on my Windows PC, and I have been using Spyder IDE. Now I want to do a project with OpenCV.

However, I have tried to install OpenCV using the Command Prompt and typing the following in:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

This only gives an error message and says "pip" is not recognized as a command.

Furthermore I tried to import OpenCV into Python using the following:

```
import cv2
```

This also doesn't work

I would appreciate any help in getting OpenCV working.

Comment: Check the anaconda docs for the installation.

Comment: try this: ```conda install -c conda-forge opencv``` or open anaconda go to environments then search opencv then click and install.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Your OS. Check Your pip installation with cmd: `pip -V` and check python with: `python -V`
It seems like You don't have pip installed at all.
Than import cv2 should work.

Comment: Thanks Wiktoor, will try